# permission problems by connecting keycloak to the data base on the same pod

Tags: mysql, podman, rootless

I have a pod and in it have keycloak latest and a data base as container. I have tried mysql and postgres both. For both of them my keycloak tries to connect to the data base as a 'sa' user and can not do that. I have not such a user at all and the defined user for keycloak DB is 'keycloak'.
I am on a centOs 8 as rootless user, running the scripts in GitLab.
Dockerfile for keycloak:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak-x:latest as builder

ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_DB=mysql
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak-x:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/ /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=testpassDbpass
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=changeme
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak
EXPOSE 8443
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--hostname=keycloak.sdxo.com", "--proxy=passthrough"]
```

Mysql and other scripts in yml:

```
stages:
  - build

build_pod:
  tags:
    - auth-runner
  stage: build
  script:
    - podman pod rm -i -f user-authentification
    - podman pod create --name user-authentification -p 9175:8443/tcp
  only:
    - main
build_db:
  image: mysql:8
  tags:
    - auth-runner
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "$KEYCLOAK_DB_USER"
    - podman run -dt --name postgres --pod user-authentification -v ~/mysql_volume:/var/lib/mysql:z
      --env MYSQL_DATABASE="$KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME"
      --env MYSQL_USER=keycloak
      --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="$KEYCLOAK_DB_PASS" --expose=3306 mysql:8
  only:
    - main
build_keycloak:
  tags:
    - auth-runner
  stage: build
  script:
    - podman build -t sdx-keycloak .
    - podman run -dt --name=sdx-keycloak --pod user-authentification --expose=8443 sdx-keycloak
  only:
      - main
```

The error is:

```
Access denied for user 'sa'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
2022-02-28 12:04:39,210 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.env.int.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: keycloak-default) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sa'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

My user id:

```
uid=1000(sdxo) gid=1000(sdxo) groups=1000(semdatex),10(wheel),1001(gitlab-runner)

podman -v 3.4.2
```

Have already done podman unshare chonw 1000:1000 pathToVolume as described in https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rootless-podman-makes-sense

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why keycloak tries to connect to the DB as sa or maybe it is a rootless problem with keycloak, but I just changed the DB user in 'sa' so it works now.